# How to add page number in multipage pdf report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have created multiple pages pdf report using *iReport* as below.

[Pdf report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830904/how-do-i-add-a-second-page-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-4-7)

How to put page number like (page 1 of 2) in this pdf report ?

If i will put same in *iReport* it will take all pages as separate page and give numbers accordingly, like:

```
for page1.jrml >> page 1 of 2 and page 2 of 2
for page2.jrml >> agian same page 1 of 1
```

...

it should be like:

```
for page1.jrml >> page 1 of 3 and page 2 of 3
for page2.jrml >> page 3 of 3
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You page numbering won't be correct because by using that approach you are creating 2 reports and merging them into 1 PDF, instead of creating a single report.

If you embed the second report into the first as a subreport, the page numbering should then be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are putting the page number inside subreport. Page numbers should be in the page footer section of the main report.