# Print numbers of copies Jasper report/ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report build by parameters, with 3 columns and same value.

After that, break page.

I want to print this report with X number of copies automatically.

PS: can't loop the same document. I really need to insert "number of copies" of this documents.

```
public void imprimir(String codigo, String tamanho, Integer qtd) throws JRException
{       
    String arquivo = "relatorios_ireport/etiqueta_pausa.jasper"; //arquivo de relatorio
    java.io.InputStream file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(arquivo); //carrego o arquivo

    //NUMBER OF REPEAT
   ArrayList array_qtd = new ArrayList();        

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){  
            array_qtd.add("Número" + i);  
    }        

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dados_qtd = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(array_qtd);          

    Map parametros = new HashMap(); 

    //parametro 1 (codigo)
    parametros.put("codigo", codigo);

    //parametro 2 (tamanho)
    parametros.put("tamanho", tamanho);          

    JasperPrint printer = null;
    printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(file, parametros, dados_qtd); 

    //SHOW DIALOG REPORT
    JRViewer view = new JRViewer(printer); //preview
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(); 

        dialog.getContentPane().add(view); 
        dialog.setSize(600,300);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(jPanel2);
        dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        //DIRECT PRINT
        //JasperPrintManager.printReport(printer,false);        
}//fim imprimir
```

Comment: what do you mean by "X number of copies " ?

Comment: @Pedro [JasperReports - Batch Export Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/batchexport/index.html#batchexport)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a second page in Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830904/how-do-i-add-a-second-page-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-4-7)

Comment: In print dialog, i need number of copies pass by parameter.

Example:
I have a report with 1 page. i want to input 10 in number of copies in Print Dialog!
Then print 10 copies.

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

$
public void imprimir(String codigo, String tamanho, Integer qtd) throws JRException{

```
    String arquivo = "relatorios_ireport/etiqueta_pausa.jasper"; //arquivo de relatorio

    java.io.InputStream file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(arquivo); //carrego o arquivo

    //NUMERO DE REPETIÇÕES
    ArrayList array_qtd = new ArrayList();

    //completar as 3 colunas com mesmo valor
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){  
            array_qtd.add("Número" + i);  
    }



    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dados_qtd = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(array_qtd);  


    Map parametros = new HashMap(); 

    //parametro 1 (codigo)
    parametros.put("codigo", codigo);

    //parametro 2 (tamanho)
    parametros.put("tamanho", tamanho);



    //CRIANDO
    JasperPrint printer = null;
    printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(file, parametros, dados_qtd); 

    //exportar para pdf
       //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printer,"D://sample_report.pdf");

        if (jCheckBox_visualizar.isSelected()){

        //CHAMAR VIEW 1 DE CADA VEZ (FECHOU ABRE O OUTRO)
        JRViewer view = new JRViewer(printer); //preview
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(); //jdialog que contem o preview

        dialog.getContentPane().add(view); //adiciono o preview
        dialog.setSize(600,300);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(jPanel2);
        dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        //CHAMAR VIEW DIRETO(TODOS AS QTD DE UMA VEZ)
        //JasperViewer.viewReport(printer, false);

        }else{

        //PROBLEM SOLVED WITH EXPORTER ATRIBUTESET.ADD(NEW Copies(qtd)) qtd = number of copies i want :D

            PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            //printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
            printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(qtd));

            PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
            //printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Argox_OS-214_plus_series_PPLA", null));
            //printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA em pcestamparia", Locale.getDefault()));
            printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA", Locale.getDefault()));
            //printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("////pcestamparia//Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA", null));
            //printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("//pcestamparia/Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA", null));
            //printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("////pcestamparia//Argox_OS-214_plus_series_PPLA", Locale.getDefault()));
            JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(printer));
            SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
            configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
            configuration.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(printServiceAttributeSet);
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            //true para aprecer opções
            configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
            configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(false);

            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

            System.out.println("Inicializando impressão");  
            exporter.exportReport();  
            System.out.println("Impressão finalizada"); 



        //IMPRIMIR DIRETO
        //JasperPrintManager.printReport(printer,false);
        }


}//fim imprimir
```

$

now, my problem is print from remote computer, the printer in another computer in local network.

this code only works in local machine:

printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Argox OS-214 plus series PPLA", Locale.getDefault()));

Answer (score 0):

Just add new external parameter and show this parameter in report.

Each time when you generates report just send new incremented value for this parameter.