# How add a report to another report using Java Code (Jaspersoft Studio)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report than i fill passing parameters from java code, now i want to pass that report i generate before to another big one report.

Is an app to print labels, initially you can print a single label, but another of his funtions is to print multiples labels in a page (can be differents), so i'm trying to pass a report (Single report generate) to another report (a bigger report

This is why i try:

```
/* To fill the map */
private Map fillParameter(){
    Map parametros = new HashMap();

    parametros.put("descripcion", panelDescripcion.getText());
    parametros.put("codigo", panelCodigo.getText());
    parametros.put("lote", panelLote.getText());        
    parametros.put("material", panelMaterial.getText());
    parametros.put("estante", panelEstante.getText());
    parametros.put("referencia", panelReferencia.getText());
    parametros.put("clasificacion", panelAbc.getText());
    parametros.put("cantidad", panelCantidad.getText());
    parametros.put("rif", RIF);

    return parametros;
}
```

Make the subreport:

```
Map parameters = fillParameter();

JasperReport subReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("Etiqueta_M_H.jasper");
JasperPrint jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(subReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("slot1", jasPrint);

JasperReport mainReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("Etiqueta_Multi.jasper");
jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

In the main report i have configure a parameter name "slot1" as JasperPrint, when i run my java code and try to generate the report i get this:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unsupported subreport section type net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint.

The jrxml of the main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-26T14:30:38 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_Letter" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="612" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="70d5ae72-8b3f-4d6d-8c33-bd163aba420b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="slot1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"/>
    <parameter name="slot2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="791" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="280" height="150" uuid="fffe225f-aad7-4749-af93-a94b5199288f"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{slot1}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="310" y="10" width="280" height="150" uuid="149a74fc-47fd-4b30-b9c2-2824fc2d4a94"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{slot2}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

jrxml of single report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-26T14:47:31 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="miReporte" pageWidth="283" pageHeight="141" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="283" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="23fdb837-cf34-425a-adb9-1f28b8b92134">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="cm"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="descripcion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="codigo" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="material" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="cantidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="estante" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="referencia" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="clasificacion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="rif" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="lote" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band height="141" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="43" width="52" height="15" uuid="1c3583f3-503b-4c9b-997f-746dbd0fce77"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Descripción:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="58" width="52" height="15" uuid="ebd882a9-ee97-42cd-84b1-9ca23a37a8b4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Material:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="73" width="52" height="15" uuid="19acd15f-3c62-46b5-b2a2-2cb78728bb7a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cantidad:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="88" width="52" height="15" uuid="47d380bd-5d99-410d-ae82-ec572eb84467"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Estante:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="103" width="52" height="15" uuid="17e7b87a-5d2c-42cf-9ba0-4a4f39a40e5e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Referencia:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="118" width="52" height="15" uuid="35d54d85-996b-48d1-964d-3a273318cf08"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="true" isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Clasificación:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="43" width="180" height="15" uuid="9e1c235b-6ab2-4f24-8fdc-1a0b6ddb5868"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{descripcion}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="7" y="6" width="126" height="35" uuid="b103e1e6-856e-4205-8f55-a6aeb13a8ee7"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["logo_Burgmann2.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="58" width="100" height="15" uuid="7a0b3313-27ec-4c75-9c34-7014d949f0b1"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{material}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="73" width="100" height="15" uuid="c6f74174-825e-452b-b223-bb7584208505">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cantidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="88" width="100" height="15" uuid="fd6b48fa-73e8-4dc3-bccc-fea6068573c0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{estante}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="103" width="100" height="15" uuid="1f9a2c94-5c51-4ac8-864e-f1cc829c7235"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{referencia}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="118" width="100" height="15" uuid="d09347e7-4d56-4e54-a84b-3f2248e030ff"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{clasificacion}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="190" y="21" width="66" height="20" uuid="a679b2d4-bb0f-4eac-a736-fca8aa87de9a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="159" y="97" width="111" height="42" uuid="0a5dcab5-f2da-4432-9d12-1b022a73ef31">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.moduleWidth" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:Code128 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" moduleWidth="1.0">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$P{lote}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:Code128>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="159" y="58" width="111" height="39" uuid="3b3e7af4-d744-47ba-a333-369725dc0c42">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.moduleWidth" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:Code128 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" moduleWidth="1.0">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$P{codigo}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:Code128>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="190" y="6" width="66" height="14" uuid="ecc784c7-d196-4923-93a4-764dcaef71c3"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{rif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </background>
</jasperReport>
```

Some pics:

[image: single report (subreport)]

[image: multiple report (master)]

Comment: You should post the more strings of stacktrace & small master report (*jrxml*)

Comment: Why are you filling the subreport from java?, this seems strange, normally the subreport is filled when you fill main report (it's a subreport!), maybe you are having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PetterFriberg Is an app to print labels, initially you can print a single label, but another of his funtions is to print multiples labels in a page (can be differents), so i'm trying to pass a report (Single report generate) to another report (a bigger report), it's the firts time i'm work with subreport so that is why it is strange.

Comment: Yeah this is where you get it wrong subreport does not work like this, they are not pre-filled stuff, hence they are not of JasperPrint class but of JasperReport class,  basically you should call them in main report with data for them to fill. You can pass parameters to subreport so restructuring your reports this can be done

Comment: Check out this post, maybe it helps you. Using java and jaspersoft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830904/how-do-i-add-a-second-page-in-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-4-7